# Unable to start old version of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In one of our server (Ubuntu 16.04.6), I'm trying to install an older version (2.6, to mimic our production) of mongo DB using the instruction given [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

All commands in the instructions went well, but when I tried to execute the command to start the mongo(`sudo service mongod start`), I'm getting the below error,

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

No idea, what exactly I'm missing. Why this is not working? And how else can I install the version 2.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to execute this command to start the `mongod`.

`/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`